# Git: How to merge/rebase 2 commits that are not direct successors

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have commits like

```
Initial->FeatureX->B->C->D->FixBugInFeatureX->E->F->
```

Now i want to make a single commit out of 
   FeatureX, FixBugInFeatureX

So i tried

```
   git -rebase -i -<FeatureX>
```

I then move the commit FixBugInFeatureX right after FeatureX in the text file and changed it from `pick` to `squash`
This works if there are no conflicts. But it shows me a new branch with **ALL** rewritten commits Initial->FeatureX->B->C->D->FixBugInFeatureX->E->F.
I can merge this branch into my Head - but i still have all previous commits (where FixBugInFeatureX now contains FeatureA a second time. Even more all inbetween commits B, C, and D now exist twice.

What i want is a new commit tree like

```
Initial->FeatureX->B->C->D->E->F
```

How can i rebase like this - or do i need a different command?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your FeatureX and FixBugInFeatureX commits out (you'll be in a detached head state then ) and commit them into 2 new branches

```
git checkout <FeatureX> 
git checkout -b featureX

git checkout <FixBugInFeatureX>
git checkout -b bugfix
```

then merge those branches together so there won't be any conflicts between the original commit and it's fix

```
git merge featureX
```

then you can check your master ( or the branch containing that chain ) out

```
git checkout master
```

and run git rebase interactive mode to rebase your master branch and the branch containing the fixed version of your FeatureX.

```
git rebase -i bugfix
```

Just give your desired order to the commits and the rebase will do the rest for you ( the order in which you want the chain to be )

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

rebase --interactive does the job, if i pass the hash of the commit **before** the initial commit to squash:

```
git rebase  -i --no-autosquash "<hash of comitt BEFORE FeatureX>"
```

This will open a text file like

```
pick 07b952c some unrelated committ 
pick 6c46e25 FeatureX
pick b4bc625 B
pick f2fab98 C
pick dc6ba8b D
pick 5633408 FixBugInFeatureX
pick 077888f E
pick 0123445 F

# Rebase xxx..yyy onto zzz
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

I can now modify this file to

```
pick 07b952c some unrelated committ 
pick 6c46e25 FeatureX
squash 5633408 FixBugInFeatureX
pick b4bc625 B
pick f2fab98 C
pick dc6ba8b D
pick 077888f E
pick 0123445 F
```

And git will squash both commits together. Afterwards a editable text file will be presented where i can edit the new commit message of 6c46e25, which now also includes 5633408

This will not work satisfyingly, if a merge or push /pull has been done between both commits. This resulted i a duplicate history at least at my trials.
But besides this its exactly what i wanted. NO duplicate history.
Obviously the point is to pass the hash of the commit BEFORE the first commit to edit.